# VBA EXCEL: find method not working when looping through each cell in selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying create a macro that, after a range selection, will tell me how many 20ft or 40ft containers where found in the sample.

[image: Range Selection]

The macro basically looks for the string "1x20" or "1x40" and when either is found, the variables cont20 or cont40 will increase by 1.

the code that I have:

```
Sub containercount()

Dim count20 As Integer
Dim count40 As Integer

count20 = 0
count40 = 0 

For Each cell In Selection

If Not ActiveCell.Find("1x20", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
 count20 = count20 + 1
End If

If Not ActiveCell.Find("1x40", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
 count40 = count40 + 1
End If

Next cell

MsgBox ("Number of 20ft containers: " & count20 & vbNewLine & "Number of 40ft containers: " & count40)

End Sub
```

But the result is always zero... I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because you are searching in an empty array.

Selection should be replaced by something like `ActiveSheet.Selection`

Furthermore, You have then to use `cell.Find`, not `ActiveCell`. `ActiveCell` references to the unique cell selected.

But regardless, I would simply use a `CountIf` formula rather than a macro.

Comment: Please give an example of how to use `CountIf`

Comment: I can't right now because I don't have excell installed on my pc and I have to look up the exact formatting. Will do that tomorrow at work. Anyone else who can look it up, feel free to comment and I'll add the example to the answer and give credits where due.

Comment: I just replaced `ActiveCell.Find` with `cell.Find` and it worked! Thank you! By the way I dont use Countif because I will add a lot more  strings to be found, then VBA would be more efficient.

Comment: Right. :) Good to hear its fixed. :)